# how to get report for test cases run using command line

Tags: android, command-line, report, junit4

I have written **Junit test cases** to test my application.

I am running my test cases in command line.

I will get report in juint UIif I run it through eclipse.

But `I am running test cases in command line`. I tried to capture logcat details, it will get overflow while running many testcases.

Please suggest me how can I get detailed report for this test case runs?

Thanks for your answers in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Link here](http://zutubi.com/source/projects/android-junit-report/) i followed this tutorial and plug in to get the report.